# Nested square root of continued fraction references

Tags: reference-request, continued-fractions, nested-radicals

$$\sqrt {a_0 + \cfrac{b_1}{\sqrt{a_1 + \cfrac{b_2}{\sqrt{a_2 + \cfrac{b_3}{ \ddots }}}}}}$$
Are there any texts that explain how to deal with expressions like this?

Comment: Your question is too general. What do you want to know about them? What is the problem that you're working on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Are there any texts that explain how to deal with expressions like this ?*

[Yes](http://www.pballew.net/1935Herschfeld.pdf). Notice that continued fractions are themselves nested radicals or order $-1$. (See link for more details). So what you have there is a nested radical of order $-2$.